# How to call a script inside a template view?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm using `CodeIgniter` and I've actually created a `template.php` file which have the following structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

   <?php $this->view('partials/header') ?>

   <body class="<?= !isset($backend) ? 'off-canvas-sidebar' : '' ?>">
      <div class="wrapper ">      
         <div class="<?= isset($backend) ? 'main-panel' : '' ?>">
            <div class="content">
               <?php $this->view($content) ?>
            </div>
            <?php $this->view('partials/footer') ?>
         </div>
      </div>

      <!--   Core JS  -->
      <script src="<?= asset_url('assets/js/vendor/core/jquery/jquery.min.js'); ?>"></script>

      <?php 
         //Load dynamic scripts
         if(isset($scripts)) 
         {
            foreach($scripts as $script)
            {
               echo '<script src="'. asset_url($script). '"></script>';
            }
         }
      ?>

   </body>
</html>
```

essentially when I need to load a `view` I write in the controller:

```
$view['content'] = 'auth/login';
$view['scripts'] = ['assets/js/general/auth.js'];
$this->load->view('partials/template', $view);
```

where `content` is the path of the `view` to load inside the `template` and `scripts` contains all the javascript files which must be loaded.

The problem is that inside the `login.php` file, I have:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.card').removeClass('card-hidden');
        }, 400);
    });
    Auth.initialize(true);
</script>
```

and this code is executed before the page load, so actually I have this loading execution:

1. Load header
2. Load content with script (Auth.initialize)
3. Load the dynamic script

the `auth.js` is loaded after the step 2, so I will get an error like:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

that is because these script are loaded after.

For fix the problem I could add the script in the header but I don't want to do that.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rather use the load callback

```js
function require(url, callback) {
  var e = document.createElement("script");
  e.src = url;
  e.type = "text/javascript";
  e.addEventListener('load', callback);
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e);
}

require("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.card').removeClass('card-hidden');
    }, 400);
  });
  console.log('loaded');
});
```